# I have renamed my csrftoken using django's CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, I made similar changes in front end. But X-CSRFToken is missing in req headers

Tags: django, cookies, csrf-token, httponly

I am using two django instances. Both of them are setting the same csrftoken variable, which is causing conflicts. One of the csrftoken cookie is overwritten by other csrftoken cookie. So I am getting `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, I renamed one of my csrftoken to be `custom-csrftoken` using `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`. In my front end too, i renamed my csrftoken to be `custom-csrftoken`.

If the above approach still doesn't work, then it means x-csrftoken header is not being sent in req headers. Try setting
`CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` in django, then X-CSRFToken header will be included in request headers from front end. So There are no more conflicts

This approach resolved my issue.